# I am trying to send an email using smtplib and ssl on python but I keep getting a TupeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'

Tags: python, ssl, smtplib

I was using this video as a guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJagw7GfZcE

I don't know why I'm getting this error someone please help.

my code

```
import smtplib, ssl

port = 465

sender = "kykeedir@gmail.com"
password = -------- 
recieve = sender

message = """/
Subject: Test

This is from python!

Liljgremlin
"""

Context = ssl.create_default_context()

print("Starting to send")
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port, context=Context) as server:
    server.login(sender, password)
    server.sendmail(sender, recieve, message)

print("sent email!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't add comment so I'll make a post:

- What version of python are you using ?
- What version of smtplib do you have ?

`context` seems to have been added after version 3.3 according to:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html

Comment: I am using python 3.7.6

Comment: Can you paste the entire traceback ?